# Protect password, Javascript to PHP

Tags: passwords

Nowdays, technology changes faster. Could you please give me best technique to protect a password from contact form?

I read about functions as MD5, SHA1 but I don't know what the best options.

The idea is protect password from Javascript. Then, get value in PHP and save it in database.

Any recomendations ?
Thanks

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow - you're asking for tool/library recommendations and opinions. There is no "best" option.

Comment: @DavidMakogon tool/library ? awesome !! Which tool can you recommend me?

Answer (score 0):

Password hashing must be done server-side, client-side hashing can be done, but never replaces server side hashing.

With PHP you should use the function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), currently it uses the BCrypt algorithm. Never use MD5 or SHA-* to hash passwords, those algorithms are way too fast and can be brute-forced too easily.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```